# Nominating/upvoting/promoting QGIS bug-reports at QGIS-Hub for faster fixing?

Tags: qgis

Since I started working with QGIS, I encountered several bugs that were already reported at the  [QGIS-Hub](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues). All of the bugs that limit my daily workflow in QGIS are just considered "normal" - not "blocking" or worse and have not been touched for 2 years now - I think the promotion of bugfixes would be more appropriate than just filing another ticket.

I wonder if there was any mechanism to draw more attention to specific bugs, for example a voting system like here at [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)? (The specific bug I am referring to is: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11106)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a post about this from one of the QGIS core developers:

http://nyalldawson.net/2016/08/how-to-effectively-get-things-changed-in-qgis/

How to get a bug fixed in order of speed:

1. Fix the bug yourself
2. Pay a developer to directly fix the bug
3. Raise funds to get the issue fixed (crowdfunding)
4. Ask a developer to directly fix the bug
5. File a bug report and hope it gets fixed

Your bug may take a couple of weeks to fix, or up to 10 years. But with the way QGIS has been developing it will usually be closer to the former.

But it is free software, there is no obligation to fix an issue. Especially if it is only effecting a handful of users. If it is important for your workflow it might be worth looking at sponsoring the fix. People can comment on bug reports if they are also experiencing the issue.